# Remove a row depending on a value in a previous row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame df:

```
Event       Code
Picture     hit
Picture     incorrect
Picture     hit
Picture     hit
Picture     incorrect
Picture     hit
Picture     inocrrect
Picture     hit
Picture     miss
Picture     hit
```

I want to remove all values after incorrect, so it would look like this:

```
Event       Code
Picture     hit
Picture     incorrect
Picture     hit
Picture     incorrect
Picture     inocrrect
Picture     miss
Picture     hit
```

What is the optimal way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which language you are using. For example, in R or MATLAB, which use indexing, this would be very easy. You would utilise the efficiency of indexing (in R):

```
Index <- which(DF[,2]=="incorrect")
DF <- DF[-(Index+1),]
```

Of course you can account for the fact that you could have an "incorrect" at the end, so Index+1 wouldn't make sense. This can be done with the following code added after finding the Index:

```
If(Index[ length(Index) ] == nrow(DF) ) {Index<-Index[-length(Index)]}
```

This line of code simply checks if an "incorrect" was found at the end of the data frame as described above. If it is, then we do not remove the term after this as it doesn't exist. This is doen by excluding this index from our vector 'Index'

Comment: Fyi, `Index[-length(Index)]` is `head(Index, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dplyr`'s pipe:

```
df %>%
  mutate(var=ifelse(lag(Code)=="incorrect",1,0)) %>%
  mutate(var = replace(var, is.na(var), 0))%>%
  filter(var!=1) %>%
  select(-var)

 Event      Code
1 Picture       hit
2 Picture incorrect
3 Picture       hit
4 Picture incorrect
5 Picture incorrect
6 Picture      miss
7 Picture       hit
```

**Edit**:
Check Procrastinatus Maximus's comments below for more streamlined pipe.

Comment: A much shorter way: `df %>% filter(lag(Code) != 'incorrect' | is.na(lag(Code)))`